# Read a text and click on a particular row of a table using Selenium in Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, html-table

I am trying to read and click a value in a row (row width=85) of table using Selenium. So far I tried these two methods, but unable to locate value. I am attaching html code as image.

```
findElementByXpath("//table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]");

findElementByXpath("//table[@width=\"85\"]/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]");
```

[image: table html code]

Any help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rely on the `id` attributes to get the table element and get the first `td` with `width="85"`inside:

```
findElementByXpath('//div[@id="Display"]/table[@id="tblData"]//td[@width="85"]')
```

Note that relying on the `width` attribute doesn't seem very reliable. Alternatively, use indexes - get the second `td` in the first `tr` tag inside the table (indexing starts from 1):

```
findElementByXpath('//div[@id="Display"]/table[@id="tblData"]//tr[1]/td[2]')
```

Comment: alecxe, thank you for the help, a slight change in Xpath worked.  findkElementByXpath("//div[@id=\"Display\"]/table[@id=\"tblData\"]//tr[2]/td[2]"); or   findElementByXpath("//div[@id=\"Display\"]/table[@id=\"tblData\"]//td[@width=\"85\"]");

Comment: You can also try out like: `findElementByXpath(//table[@id='tblData']//td[contains(text(),'<your text>')])`